# PhpStorm - how to turn off automatic curly brace insertion

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, reactjs

Currently, I am using PhpStorm for JavaScript programming (React framework). In React, there is added special syntactic sugar called JSX, which allows inserting HTML into JavaScript code.
But phpstorm gets wrong when I insert some specific JSX, so then always when I hit enter to go to the next line, it inserts additional unwanted `{`. Is there any way, how to suppress this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the settings you're interested in under **Settings > Editor > Smart Keys**. The one you want to uncheck is **Insert pair '}'**. If that alone doesn't do exactly what you want, you could also uncheck **Insert pair bracket**.

Comment: Found at Settings > Editor > **General** > Smart Keys